# Calabrese: origine di certe -n- infisse

Tags: etymology, regional

Quest'anno sono entrato in contatto con una canzone calabrese, "la mamma" (o magari "di mamma nci nde una sula"). Una delle strofe recita:

> Sugnu cuntentu e nun fazzu misteri
>   Chi me mamma mi fici li peri:
>   Mi i fici quaranta e mmenzu,
>   Unu quaranta e l'autru menzu.

"Menzu" vuol dire "mezzo". Notavo quella "n" in più. Un'altra canzone calabrese, che ho conosciuto l'anno scorso, ha una strofa che recita:

> A casa tegnu durici vistiti,
>   Ottu di carta e quattru di cartuni,
>   Chi mmi li mentu quandu mi maritu.
>   Chi bella cosa mi facimm'ammuri.

E qua abbiamo "mentu", che, come s'intuisce dal contesto e mi è poi stato confermato da uno di laggiù, vuol dire "indosso", quindi "metto". E ritroviamo la "n" in più che c'era in "menzu".

Non ho altri esempi da portare, ma mi chiedevo da dove provengono queste "n" infisse. Queste parole calabresi sono etimologicamente correlate alle rispettive traduzioni italiane, o sono completamente scollegate e solo per caso somigliano alle traduzioni? E nel primo caso, da dove saltano fuori quelle "n"?

Comment: Trovo che questa domanda sia più fuori tema che no. Il calabrese è un'altra lingua rispetto all'italiano standard, anche se sono entrambe derivate dal latino: è più o meno come porre una domanda sul francese. Se n'era parlato sul Meta, [qui](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31/are-questions-about-dialects-on-topic) e altrove.

Comment: @DaG L'ho posta qui perché pensavo al Calabrese come un dialetto dell'Italiano, e su Chinese stack exchange accettano domande sui dialetti (ne ho poste parechie su Min Nan e Hakka). Ho sospettato che fosse fuori tema quando ho visto che mancava il tag [tag:dialetto], ma l'ho posta lo stesso. Dove potrei riporla nel caso fosse chiusa come fuori tema?

Comment: Naturalmente intendevo [tag:dialect], non [tag:dialetto].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il fenomeno riscontrato è noto nella fonetica storica come **[epentesi](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/epentesi_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/) di una nasale** (cfr. *Rohlfs*, Grammatica storica della lingua italiana e dei suoi dialetti, Vol.1 §334).

La dissimilazione di una consonante intensa per mezzo dell'epentesi di una nasale anorganica è un fenomeno poligenetico, ma è peculiare la frequenza con cui essa si verifica nei dialetti del Meridione estremo, calabresi e salentini in primis.

Tale tendenza è stata messa in rapporto con la gennerale debolezza articolatoria delle [geminate](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/geminato/) nel greco medievale, con cui notoriamente queste varietà si trovarono in prolungato contatto durante il Medioevo e anche oltre.

Si possono distinguere i seguenti risultati per **mezzo**:  *mènzu* (Sicilia), *mienzu* ovvero *mènzu* (Calabria), *miensu* ovvero *mènsu* (Salento).

La forma *menzu* è niente altro che un adattamento della forma letteraria *mezzo* al sistema fonetico meridionale, al quale la consonante *z* geminata (-zz-) allungata è poco familiare.

Analogamente per *mettere* con la geminata *t* diviene *mentere*.

Comment: Dunque menzu e mentiri sono essenzialmente prestiti dall'Italiano, con le geminate che si degeminano r si prenasalizzano per questa debolezza articolatoria delle geminate ereditata dal Greco. Dico bene?